# Border Headlines

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ideally, I want to split up different headlines (and their images), using a `bottom-border`. Have tried this, but instead it puts a border on the image, instead of between headlines.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({

    url: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=the-sport-bible&apiKey=7822ca100cdf43e1a85e1e101aa69c06",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      processData(data);
    }
  });


  function processData(data) {
    var articleItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

      var author = data.articles[i].author;
      var title = data.articles[i].title;
      var description = data.articles[i].description;
      var urlToImage = data.articles[i].urlToImage;
      var artUrl = data.articles[i].url;


      var $author      = `<div class="author">Author: ${author}</div >`
      var $title       = `<a href="${artUrl}"><div class="title">${title}</div ></a>`
      var $description = `<a href="${artUrl}"><div class="description">${description}</div></a>`
      var $urlToImage  = `<a href="${artUrl}"><img class="urlToImage" src="${urlToImage}">`;

      $("#sport_news").append(`${author}${$title}${$description}${$urlToImage}`);
      $("#sport_news").append("<br />");

      console.log(artUrl);
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="sport">
        <h3>SPORT</h3>
        <p id="sport_news"></p>
      </div>
```

Comment: what css are you attaching the `border-bottom` to?

Comment: I have a CSS file, I just haven't attached it. I'm just not sure what ID's or classes to use reference in the CSS .

Comment: add the css for `tab-pane`, `fade`, `sport` and `sports_news`, as well as any relevant css that affects the div section you included (ie `div`, `h3` and `p` if they affect the `html` segment).  The javascript doesn't look to be part of the issue here, but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the top and bottom lines below where you append your html:

```
  $("#sport_news").append("<div style='border-bottom: 2px solid;' >");
  $("#sport_news").append(`${author}${$title}${$description}${$urlToImage}`);
  $("#sport_news").append("<br />");
  $("#sport_news").append("</div>");
```

This code uses inline styling so you should add a class to the div and move the styling to there.

Best practice would be to add a class attribute to the div like:

```
$("#sport_news").append("<div class='headline'>");
```

And define your class in an external stylesheet like:

```
.headline
{
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```